# pyMySql on Visual Studio code

Tags: python, sql, installation

How do I install pyMySql on Python?

Thanks

Comment: $ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL

Comment: Obrigado Bruno! Mas não funciona! já instalei o pymysql, mas simplesmente a visual studio só aparece ''unresolved import 'pymysql'Python(unresolved-import)'... já instalei o python 3.5, 3.7, 3.8... em todos consigo intalar o pymysql, mas o Vs code não reconhece. No pycharm funciona de boa. Mas quero montar uma linha de estuo com o Vs Code. :(

Comment: O vscode deve ser parecido com o Jupyter, bem chatinho de descobrir qual é o python sendo usado... Vc já tentou usar o console do vscode?

Comment: Encontrei um cara no youtube explicando... eu então consegui conectar usando:  pip install mysql-connector-python. Mas só funcionou na versão 3.8.2 do Python! Valew!!!